# Heroku/Express: "Not Found" When Attempting To Access A Sub-Route (On Refresh)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, heroku

I have a React Web App deployed to Heroku and running on an Express/Node.js server. When someone tries to access any route my server index.js file runs the following code:

```
const path = require('path')
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html'))
})
```

When I load the app from the root route ('/') everything is fine, and as I navigate through the app (using React Router) everything is still fine. The problem happens when I attempt to refresh from a sub-route (e.g., /contact), then I get a "Not Found" error. And when I check the Heroku logs I see this message:

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/client/build/index.html'
```

I should note I am running the build script on the server, and when I login to Heroku I can see the "build" folder and all contents, including "index.html", are present.

I should also note I have tried other sendFile configurations with no luck, such as:

```
res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname + '/client/build/index.html'))
```

Does anyone know what the problem might be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out what the problem was, I simply had the path wrong. It should be:

```
res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname + '/app/client/build/index.html'))
```

*Added the '/app' part*